# Google Domains With Amazon's EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, elastic-ip

I am hosting my website on Amazon's EC2 with an elastic IP address. My domain is purchased through Google Domains.

When I go to `www.example.com`, the website loads.

If I go to `example.com`, it doesn't load.

Is there a way to change my configuration to have both work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure an `A` record for `example.com` on Google DNS to point to the Elastic IP address.

You should then configure an additional `CNAME` record for `www.example.com` to point to `example.com`.